# Tableviews delegate eats button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I got a large UITableViewCell representing a place. Elements of the cell are two Buttons **starButton** and **infoButton**. Both of them have a targetAction which never gets executed and I'm clueless why.. All touches are being eaten by the `didSelectRowAt` by the tableview. The thing that gets me so confused is the fact that It all worked well some hours ago and I did not change properties of the two buttons. Does someone has an idea what's going on?

The Hierarchy looks like this:

> UITableView
>
> > OverviewTableCell `UITableViewCell`
> >
> > > dotsButton, **thumbnailImageView** `UIButton` , `UIImageView`
> > >
> > > > blackView `UIView`
> > > >
> > > > > titleLabel, descriptionLabel, starButton, infoButton `UILabel` , `UIButton`

---

Cell:

```
class OverviewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, ReusableView {

    lazy var dotsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: GSSettings.UI.otherIcons.dotsHorizontal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: GSSettings.UI.otherIcons.dotsVertical)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .selected)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seeMore), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.fixHeightAndWidth(width: 28, height: 28)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        return button
    }()

    let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageview.clipsToBounds = true
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "testbild")
        return imageview
    }()

    let blackView: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35)
        return imageview
    }()

    let titleLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Titel Titel"
        label.font = GSSettings.UI.Fonts.helveticaMedium?.withSize(22)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        return label
    }()

    lazy var starButton: GSFavSpotButton = {
        let button = GSFavSpotButton()
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white//GSSettings.UI.Colors.nightOrange
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleStarButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    lazy var infoButton: GSInfoButton = {
        let button = GSInfoButton()
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white//GSSettings.UI.Colors.nightOrange
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInfoButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    let addFriendView = GSInviteAFriendView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        setupSubviews()
        setupConstraints()
        perform(#selector(printBounds), with: nil, afterDelay: 5)
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        self.addSubview(dotsButton)
        self.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        thumbnailImageView.addSubview(blackView)
        blackView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        blackView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        blackView.addSubview(starButton)
        blackView.addSubview(infoButton)
        self.addSubview(addFriendView)

        blackView.isHidden = true
        descriptionLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        dotsButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeading: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 16, width: 0, height: 0)


        thumbnailImageView.anchor(top: dotsButton.bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeading: 16, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 16, width: 0, height: 0)
        thumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thumbnailImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 9/16).isActive = true
        blackView.fillSuperview(unsafeArea: true)

        titleLabel.anchor(top: thumbnailImageView.topAnchor, leading: thumbnailImageView.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: starButton.leadingAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeading: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 8, width: 0, height: 20)

        infoButton.anchor(top: thumbnailImageView.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: thumbnailImageView.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeading: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 8, width: 30, height: 30)
        starButton.anchor(top: thumbnailImageView.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: infoButton.leadingAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeading: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 4, width: 30, height: 30)

        addFriendView.anchor(top: thumbnailImageView.bottomAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, paddingTop: -GSSettings.UI.Sizes.addFriendButtonSize/2 + 10, paddingLeading: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 0, width: GSSettings.UI.Sizes.addFriendButtonSize, height: GSSettings.UI.Sizes.addFriendButtonSize)
        addFriendView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func seeMore() {
        dotsButton.isSelected.toggle()
        if dotsButton.isSelected {
            blackView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            blackView.isHidden = false
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @objc func handleStarButton() {
        starButton.isSelected.toggle()
    }

    @objc func handleInfoButton() {
        infoButton.isSelected.toggle()
    }

    @objc func printBounds() {
        print("::::")
        print(thumbnailImageView.bounds)
        print(infoButton.bounds)
        print(starButton.bounds)
        print("_____")
        print(thumbnailImageView.frame)
        print(infoButton.frame)
        print(starButton.frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension UIView {
  func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,  paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeading: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingTrailing: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
    }

    if let leading = leading {
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: paddingLeading).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
    }

    if let trailing = trailing {
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -paddingTrailing).isActive = true
    }

    if width != 0 {
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }

    if height != 0 {
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OverviewTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! OverviewTableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    delegate?.pushTo()
}
```

The printBounds() function in the cell shows that the frame and bounds are okay (I guess)

> (0.0, 0.0, 382.0, 215.0)
>   (0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0)
>   (0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0)
>
> ---
>
> (16.0, 32.0, 382.0, 215.0)
>   (344.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0)
>   (310.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

also add the subviews to

`self.contentView` and create the constraints of cell subviews with it

Comment: `blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` solved the issue! Thanks!

What is the purpose of using the contentView?